# Best way to say after calling someone and no answer!

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

What is the best formal way to document when you called someone and did not succeed to get hold of him/her?

I am usually documented the case as calling Mr X but no answer, but have the feeling could be much more better than this simple words.

Comment: What is the document? I would not use the same words in my diary as I would, say, a call log at a help center.

Comment: document that I must record all my actions; I want to know just to expand my knowledge

Answer (score 3):

You can note your unanswered call down in several ways, including:

> No answer
>
> No reply
>
> No response

See a previous similar question and the answers to it at:

[What are the differences between response and answer?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/what-are-the-differences-between-response-and-answer)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you called the person via a direct-dial phone (one where Mr X would answer himself) of via a telephonist or personal assistant.

For a direct-dial phone, you could say

> but I got no answer
>   but he did not answer
>   but he did not pick up

If you had to go through and exchange and nobody answered, you could say

> I called Mr X's office but I got no answer
>   I called Mr X's office but nobody answered

If you did speak to somebody else, then it is better to say

> but I couldn't get hold of him

or, if the person who offered a reason for his unavailability, you could quote the reason

> but he was not at his desk
>   but he was on holiday
>   but he was out to lunch

Comment: One more that could be used: "We tried reaching you [to no avail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20no%20avail)."

Answer (score 0):

> I called Mr. X but nobody answered.

or

> I called Mr. X but nobody picked up (the phone).